# Example 15 Learn Python the Hard Way

Tags: python

The study drills ask me to close the file after I'm done with it. I tried it like this:

```
from sys import argv

script, file = argv

txt = open(file)

print "Here's your file %r:" % file
print txt.read()

print txt.close()
```

All that does it print out "none" when running the script. I thought it would clear the text file. By closing it what is it doing? I don't want to get far ahead if that's what it seems.

Comment: Closing free's up the resources associated with an open file, e.g. file descriptors. You may also want to look into python's `with` statement that will safely ensure that files (resources) are properly released when the `with` block exits, even in the event of exceptions.

Comment: The title of the question is vague. Does not describe the question in any sense. To answer your query, `file.close()` returns `None` and hence it is in the output.

Answer (score 6):

`close` is a method, that have no return value. In Python this no value is equal to `None`. Printing the result of `close` is therefore not very informative.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through the code in detail

```
from sys import argv
```

`argv` is a list that contains the parameters provided to the script on the command line, e.g. `python script.py hello.txt` makes `argv` be `['script.py', 'hello.txt']`

```
script, file = argv
```

assigns the element of `argv` to the variables `script` and `file`

```
txt = open(file)
```

opens the file for reading, `txt` is a file object (i.e. a handler to the file)

```
print "Here's your file %r:" % file
```

prints the text given substituting the `%r` with the filename

```
print txt.read()
```

read the contents of the file and prints them out

```
print txt.close()
```

as said before, there is no point in printing out the value returned by `close`, which is `None`.

instead, just do

```
txt.close()
```

Mind you, normally, you'd use a context manager (see [this tutorial](http://kentsjohnson.com/kk/00015.html)) to make sure files are opened and always closed

```
with open(file) as txt:
    print txt.read()
```

In case you want to clear the contents of the file after having printed them out, you can

```
with open(file, 'r+') as txt: # opens the file for reading and writing
    print txt.read()
    txt.seek(0) # moves back the cursor
    txt.truncate()  # truncates the file's size
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `close` the file you aren't removing the content of it you are simply removing the lock you have on it to tell other processes that you have it open and to prevent it from being deleted while you write to it.

Answer (score 0):

From Python's standpoint

Its a method with no return type, which is equivalent to None as you can see.

From actual working standpoint

It removes your write lock on the resource. Read more about it in databases for race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

A nicer way to code file IO is with `with`.  It automatically closes the file.  For example:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()
    print(content)   #prints it

print(content)       #also prints it.  Does not go out of scope
```

where 'r' is for read, 'w' for write, 'a' for append.